# Issue while trying to install an application using .appinstaller

Tags: store, appinstaller

Getting issue while trying to install an application using .appinstaller.

I am trying to install an app using .appinstaller. However, getting below error which is blocking to proceed with the installation:

App installation failed with error message: The package full name returned from the AppxManifest (AppName_neutral_~*xxxxx) does not match the name generated from the AppInstaller (AppName_neutral*~_yyyyyy). Please ensure that the package attributes specified in the .appinstaller file match the package attributes referenced in aaaaa.msixbundle. (0x8008020c)

Looking for help to resolve this.